# Changing position of Phaser.Text when fixedToCamera

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

How do I go about changing the position of a Phaser.Text element when it has the attribute fixedToCamera set to true. In the below code the value of counterText.x is always reset to 45;

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(500, 500, 'phaser-example', { create: create, update: update});

var counter = 0;

function create() {
  counterText = game.add.text(45, 45, 'Text', {
    font: "26px Verdana",
    fill: "#fff"
  });
  counterText.fixedToCamera = true;
}

function update() {
 counterText.x = counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reckon the problem here is that when fixedToCamera is true, Text doesn't use 'position' anymore, but uses 'cameraOffset' instead. So if you modify that as you would the position, everything should work fine.